# If a function is never called does the compiler omit it when creating the program?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

When the compiler runs its optimizations, does it omit functions that are never called? I remember reading something that says not to include unnecessary files because it will create needless bloat in a program so I can only assume from that statement that when it's compiled it does include said functions that are never used, but I don't see any logical reason for a compiler not to remove them and I would assume that most modern compilers would probably remove extra unused functions.

Comment: If this happened I don't think public functions would exist.  I could be wrong, as I have not taken compiler theory in years.

Comment: Never called, or never referenced? In general, it is not possible for a compiler to determine whether a function will ever be called.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, the answer is 'no'. But some compilers will eliminate some functions in some specific cases. And the linker will also not include functions from statically linked libraries that are in source files in which no function in that file is needed.

One common case that's usually eliminated is a static function that is never called and who's address is never taken. Another is a static function that's inlined everywhere it's called and who's address is never taken.

It's completely up to the compiler.

But, in general, it's very hard to do because the compiler doesn't usually have a view of the whole program to build a comprehensive call graph. And the linker isn't smart enough.

Additionally, some files may end up being parts of libraries. And the whole purpose of libraries is to have a bunch of code that's not called from the library itself. The compiler cannot determine at compile time whether a given piece of code is going into a library or not. So again, that means for functions with 'external linkage', it's up to the linker to elide them if they aren't used.

Comment: `the compiler doesn't usually have a view of the whole program to build a comprehensive call graph. And the linker isn't smart enough.` Now that LTO is widely available, the compiler & linker can communicate so closely that they're effectively can a single unit, for which neither of these statements is true. GCC's `-flto`, for instance, talks of how it streams all translation units together into 1, for which a whole-program call-graph is built, thus allowing intense optimisation. Resulting stack traces (or undefined references!) show incredible levels of inlining & other optimisations going on

Comment: @underscore_d - Does the compiler also use this to improve the situation for template instantiation? The whole "I'm going to emit this function definition as a weak symbol and pray to the great random that all the other compilation units emitted the same code for this symbol so when the linker randomly picks one it gets it right." seemed really dodgy to me.

Comment: Good question - I don't know either way; I didn't look at that case in any detail. Anyway, weak symbols are still largely voodoo to me. Surely, though, they all have to exhibit equivalent behaviour, so it wouldn't matter which got picked? Or if the template arguments differ, the instantiated functions aren't candidates for merging, so it doesn't matter. But I probably misunderstood most of this. :P

Comment: How can visual studio easily tell me "hey this function/class/struct is never used" but a compiler can't figure that out and omit it ?

Comment: @WDUK - Interestingly, whole program static analysis tools are easier to write because it's OK if they make the occasional mistake. Additionally, they don't have to deal with "this is going to be compiled into a static library, this into a shared library that may or may not be loaded by a program depending on it's runtime behavior" and so on. There are a ton of cases in the real world that a whole program static analysis tool can conveniently ignore.

Answer (score 4):

It will largely depend on the compiler, but yes, in some setups the compiler can completely eliminate the functions that are not called. The compiler must ensure that the function is indeed never called.

Specifically functions that are marked `static` can be eliminated quite easily - just look in the same translation unit. It gets harder if a function can potentially be called from another translation unit. Visual C++ has a special setting for this, called "function-level linking" and a linker settings [for removing unreferenced functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). When these two are used together the unreferenced functions will be eliminated completely.

Answer (score 3):

It *can* do. C++ compilers merely operate under the *as-if* rule. As long as the resulting program behaves as the standard dictates, the compiler can do whatever it likes to get there.

> conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine

If the function is never called, then of course the compiler *could* get rid of it, but it's entirely up to the compiler whether it does or not. However, the compilation model of C++ requires that translation units are compiled separately. It is often impossible or very difficult for the compiler to know that the function is never called from any other translation unit.